# Android N FileUriExposedException

Tags: camera, file-uri, android-7.1-nougat

Guys My app uses the stock camera to take a picture I use the following code to take a picture

```
public void takepic(View view) {

        TextView schtitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Sitename);
        String schname = schtitle.getText().toString();
            String[] tokens = schname.split(" ");
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm-ss").format(new Date());
            String imageFileName = tokens[0] + "-" + timeStamp + ".jpg";
            TextView myAwesomeTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.filetext);

          //in your OnCreate() method
          myAwesomeTextView.setText(imageFileName);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);    


                File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
                String name = imageFileName;
                File file = new File(path, name );
                outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
                startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE); 


       }
```

This works fine in all but Nougat

I understand as they did in marshmallow you now need permissions and cant use file URI anymore

I cant find any sample code on how to take a picture in nougat could someone please point me in the right direction as to how I modify my code to allow this to happen?

Any help appreciated

Mark

Comment: Use `FileProvider`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/FileProvider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the file:// uri is not permited anymore.

Instead of this you must use FileProvider.

Take a look here: https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-share-access-to-file-with-fileprovider-on-android-nougat/en

Answer (score 0):

Just quoting this here for reference.

We now have an updated documentation on how to use camera intent with a file uri to store the taken picture under the training section of android.

https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void openShare(View view) {
        // save bitmap to cache directory
        try {
            bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) iv.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

            File cachePath = new File(getCacheDir(), "images");

            if (!cachePath.exists())
                cachePath.mkdirs();

            FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(cachePath + "/" + imageName);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            stream.close();

            shareImage();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void shareImage() {
        File imagePath = new File(getCacheDir(), "images");
        File newFile = new File(imagePath, imageName);
        Uri contentUri = MyFileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.example.kushaalsingla.contentsharingdemo", newFile);

        if (contentUri != null) {
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION); // temp permission for receiving app to read this file
            shareIntent.setDataAndType(contentUri, getContentResolver().getType(contentUri));
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Choose an app"));
        }
    }
```

################## Add in Manifest

```
       <provider
            android:name=".MyFileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.kushaalsingla.contentsharingdemo"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
        </provider>
```

################## filepaths.xml ########################

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <cache-path name="shared_images" path="images/"/>
</paths>
```