# FileUriExposedException using Android 7

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

When I try to capture a picture I have this error :

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                      android.os.FileUriExposedException:
>   file:///storage/emulated/0/fname_1498727381241.jpg exposed beyond app
>   through ClipData.Item.getUri()
>                                                                          at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:1799)
>                                                                          at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2346)
>                                                                          at android.content.ClipData.prepareToLeaveProcess(ClipData.java:835)
>                                                                          at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:9514)
>                                                                          at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:9499)
>                                                                          at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1525)
>                                                                          at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4403)
>                                                                          at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4362)
>                                                                          at
>   opteamit.com.belami.CommuniquerPartagerPhotosActivity$1.onClick(CommuniquerPartagerPhotosActivity.java:46)
>                                                                          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6261)
>                                                                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23752)
>                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                          at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)

It was working before but it seem the problem is since I use Android 7 (API 24).

This is my code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                imageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "fname_" +
                        String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"));
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: We have it on official training docs now. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44840358/1987045) answer.

Comment: Use File Provider  from API Level 24 in Android.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> If your targetSdkVersion is 24 or higher, we have to use FileProvider
>   class to give access to the particular file or folder to make them
>   accessible for other apps. We create our own class inheriting
>   FileProvider in order to make sure our FileProvider doesn't conflict
>   with FileProviders declared in imported dependencies as described
>   here.

Find relevant discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed/38858040#38858040)

Since Android 7, we don't use file: scheme as uri for intent, you have to use FileProvider.

Answer (score 23):

Well, the correct way of doing it is by using `FileProvider`([as mentioned in developer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider)). But I have figured out a naughty way to do it without adding `FileProvider`. It is obviously a workaround but it works.

In your Activity, add the following lines:

```
 StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
 StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
```

This will simply ignore the URI exposure and you will get the access.

Yes, I know that this is not the best practice. But I just wanted to provide an alternative to it.

Still, recommended way is by using `FileProvider`.

Comment: it works. I added this in my activity where I open the local HTML document.

Comment: Great bro.. tq so much

Comment: This don´t must be used in a producction app.